Prove $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos((\pi-x)w)+\cos(xw)}{1-w^2} \,dw = f(x)$ for given function
Prove that
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos((\pi-x)w)+\cos(xw)}{1-w^2} \,dw = f(x)$$
where the function $f(x)$ is given by
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \sin x&\text{if}\, x\in [0,\pi]\
 \\
     0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
I found the Fourier transform to be:
$$f(w)=\frac{i\sin{w\pi}-\cos{w\pi}-1}{2\pi(w^2-1)}$$
How do I proceed?

Take the inverse transform: $f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(w)e^{-iwx}dw$. For this last step note that in general $\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(w)dw = \int_{0}^\infty (F(w) + F(-w))dw$.

Integrate as follows
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos[(\pi-x)w]+\cos(xw)}{1-w^2} 
\overset{w\to -w}{dw} \\
=& \ \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos[(\pi-x)w]+\cos(xw)}{1-w^2} dw\\
=& \ \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(\frac\pi2 w)\cos[(\frac\pi2 -x)w]\bigg(\frac1 {\underset{t=1-w}{1-w}}+ \frac1 {\underset{t=1+w}{1+w}}\bigg) dw\\
 =& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{ \sin[x+(\frac\pi2 -x)t] \sin(\frac\pi2 t)}t dt\\
 =& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x \cos [(\frac\pi2-x)t] \sin(\frac\pi2 t)}t dt\\
=& \ \frac{\sin x }2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{  \sin(x t)+\sin[(\pi-x)t]}t dt\\
=& \ 
\begin{cases}
\pi \sin x & x\in [0,\pi]\
 \\
     0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where
$
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{ \sin(a t)}t dt=\text{sgn}(a)\pi $ is applied.

Congratulations for the 100k reputation !
